# Postgresql :unable to Install HTTP extension on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-rds, postgresql-extensions

I am trying to get response from API into Postsgresql.
For this I have installed respective HTTP extension 
from

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/371-http-extension-for-windows-64-and-32-bit.html

In my local system .
Current issue is that my database server is on amazon aws. So now I want to replicate same files/modules on server.
But I'm not much aware about it.
While I have tried

```
create extension http
```

then after I tried to get to know the supported extension by using this

```
show rds.extensions
```

Then I didn't found the `HTTP` extension there.

SO please let me know how can I place downloaded `HTTP` extension file on amazon rds??

Answer (score 2):

If the extension is not among the supported ones from ...

```
SHOW rds.extensions;
```

... then you are out of luck, for all I know.

In particular, the "http extension" requires to install binaries in the file system of a Windows server.

The RDS Postgres installations I know run on Red Hat Linux, not Windows. And Amazon does not allow direct access to the underlying file system - which can be a pain. We tried to install additional unaccent dictionaries, but no dice.

You could talk to their support, maybe you have more luck.

Comment: can i install HTTP  extension with  the help of dblink extension on my another azure server and connect to it with amazon rds??